# jQuery: Why Won't This For Loop Work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, for-loop

Fairly specific question here. I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cartButArr = document.querySelectorAll(".toCart")

    for(i=0; i<cartButArr.length; i++){
        cartButArr[i].onclick = cartAdd();
    }
});
```

And later, the called function:

```
function cartAdd() {
    alert("yo!");
}
```

However, this for loop, for whatever reason, will not work properly. When I start up the page, I get a series of six alerts in a row, rather than an alert being called whenever I click. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't jQuery. If you're going to use jQuery, then **use jQuery**. Replace your with `$('.toCart').click(cartAdd)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very minor typo is preventing the loop from working. Change

`cartButArr[i].onclick = cartAdd();`

to

`cartButArr[i].onclick = cartAdd;`

The reason it does not work is that `cartAdd()` invokes the cartAdd() function, triggering the alert. You saw the alert multiple times, because the loop called cartAdd() each time. Want you intended to do was assign the function to the callback handler, not invoke the function.

Comment: Blaaah - it's always some tiny typo. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The onclick event should be attached to a function to be called when that event fires

What you are doing is actually calling the function cartAdd and assigning it's value to onclick, which doesn't recognize it's result as a function

Replace your line

```
cartButArr[i].onclick = cartAdd();
```

with this one

```
cartButArr[i].onclick = cartAdd;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
cartButArr[i].onclick = cartAdd();
```

so instead of **assigning** a callback function, you're **executing** it.

Correct syntax would be:

```
cartButArr[i].onclick = cartAdd;
```

(no parenthesis after function name).